# SQL Group By custom range?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, case

I have a table that stores pizza orders. The table has a value called quantity; the amount of pizzas in that specific order. I need to "create a query that gets the distribution of orders against different pizza quantities in an order. The questions states"Your sql query should count the number of orders with the following pizza quantities: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and above 6". After researching for a while i came up with this query, but it doesnt work the way I would like. Here is the query and its results. Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN Quantity = 1 THEN '1 ' 
    WHEN Quantity = 2 THEN '2' 
    WHEN Quantity = 3 THEN '3 ' 
    WHEN quantity = 4 THEN '4' 
    WHEN quantity = 5 THEN '5 '  
    WHEN quantity = 6 THEN '6' 
    ELSE '>6' 
    END AS Range, COUNT(Quantity) AS Amount
FROM  orders
GROUP BY Quantity
```

This outputs :

```
Range     Amount
1         2
2         3
3         3
4         4
5         5
6         1
>6        1
>6        2
>6        2
>6        1
```

How would i go about grouping the >6 range and counting the Amount's. so that it is under a single '>6' entry?

Comment: can you use group by "Range" instead of Quantity..

Comment: Please pick one platform. Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? They're different - have you read anything about the tags before you applied them to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way is using the same `CASE WHEN` statement for the `GROUP BY` clause, for example* :

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN Quantity <= 6 THEN CAST(Quantity as VARCHAR(1))
    ELSE '>6' 
    END AS Range, COUNT(Quantity) AS Amount
FROM  orders
GROUP BY (CASE 
    WHEN Quantity <= 6 THEN CAST(Quantity as VARCHAR(1))
    ELSE '>6' 
    END)
```

*) Using simplified version of your original `CASE WHEN` statement. Written in SQL Server flavor of SQL.

Answer (score 3):

Run this query instead of your previous one:

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN Quantity = 1 THEN '1 ' 
WHEN Quantity = 2 THEN '2' 
WHEN Quantity = 3 THEN '3 ' 
WHEN quantity = 4 THEN '4' 
WHEN quantity = 5 THEN '5 '  
WHEN quantity = 6 THEN '6' 
ELSE '>6' 
END AS Range, COUNT(Quantity) AS Amount
FROM  orders
GROUP BY Range
```

Comment: This presents an error - Invalid column name (Range)

Comment: dynamically evaluated columns (like `Range` in this query) won't be recognized in `GROUP BY` clause, so this query won't even run

Comment: @Riad, sorry, it seems the question was about SQL-Server, not MySQL. The OP had tagged incorrectly. I edited the question and removed the mysql tag.

Comment: Alex94, that's why you should tag your question with the proper DBMS - and not any others. MySQL is different than SQL-Server.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT IF(Quantity > 6,'>6',Quantity) AS Range, (Quantity*Amount) AS Amount
FROM  orders